# Find the function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3(-1)^{n+1}(3x)^{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

I've got a problem with this: 
Given
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3(-1)^{n+1}(3x)^{n-1}$$
Find the domain of the function $f$ and calculate for $x\in D$ the value of $f$.


I've found the domain which is $(\frac{-1}3,\frac13)$ by putting $|3x|<1$ since it needs to be less than one to converge and I've tried semplifying the series to get something similar to a Taylor's expansion but i cannot find anything even remotely similar to the known ones.

I'd appreciate some help :)

Thank you :)

Comment: Why did you put the "functional analysis" tag on your post. Read the tag's description before using it -> """ Functional analysis, the study of infinite-dimensional vector spaces, often with additional structures (inner product, norm, topology), with typical examples given by function spaces. The subject also includes the study of linear and non-linear operators on these spaces and other topics. For basic questions about functions use more suitable tags like (functions), (functional-equations) or (elementary-set-theory). """

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3(-1)^{n+1}(3x)^{n-1}$$

Let $m=n-1,$

$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}3(-1)^{m+2}(3x)^{m}=3\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-3x)^{m}=\frac{3}{1+3x}$$

Comment: Use ratio test to find the convergent interval which is the domain @BlobFish